# How can I post data to php and print that data?

Tags: python, php, python-requests, undefined-index

I tried *requests* module but I've error in my php outputs: The error is: **Notice: Undefined index: firstname in D:\xampp\htdocs\myfile\receive.php on line 7
NULL**

code in python: 
''' 
payload = {'firstname':'Jack'} 
url = "http://localhost/myfile/receive.php" 
resp = requests.post(url, data=payload) 
print(resp.status_code)
text =resp.text
print(text)
''' 
**status_code is ok(200)!**

php code: 
$data = $_POST["firstname"]; 
var_dump($data);

It seems okay but it's not :)

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you get in php script.

Comment: please use isset() when handling POST / GET / COOKIE / SESSION variables

Comment: Not sure what the python code will send your payload as - is it sending it as JSON, perhaps? Then you would have to receive it differently in PHP - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: P.s., please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @Lessmore the output of python is:  <br/> 'array(1) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(4) "jack"
}  '   <br/>             but my browser shows me:  ' array(0) { }'

Comment: @KenLee I tried this 'if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
    var_dump($_POST['firstname']);
    echo 'P';
}else{
    echo 'There is nothing to show';
}' <br/>   the output in python was:' string(4) "jack" ' but in browser : There is nothing to show!

Answer (score 0):

In your php code, you have to use $_REQUEST["firstname"];

```
$data = $_REQUEST["firstname"]
```

instead of using $_POST